# Enity and stored procedure mapping with different data types

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity

I have created a mapping between a stored procedure and entity table. Is it possible to define conversion during mapping?

For example: One of the entity column is Datetime and the store procedure take that column as text.

I know I can update the stored procedure to have Datetime parameter, consider I cannot update stored procedure.

Using EF5 with Oracle ODP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the entity? If so you can map a private string property to your db and not map your DateTime property. Your DateTime property's getter will just get the string property and convert to datetime and the setter will convert the datetime to a string and set the private string prop.

[This article shows mapping private properties.](http://romiller.com/2013/01/23/ef6-code-first-mapping-all-private-properties-using-custom-conventions/)